# discrete random variable with cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a discrete random variable X with CDF (Cumulative
Distribution Function) () specified below:

[image]

I am just new to the course of statistics and wonder if only Pr(X=1), Pr(X=2), Pr(X=3) and Pr(X=5)are all the probabilities that can be drawn out from this cdf and other remaining probabilities like Pr(X=4)etc are equal to 0. Am I correct?

Based on my understanding, I have tried to compute the following, are they correct?
(a)For the value of Pr(2 <  ≤ 3) and Pr( = 3), I think that both Pr(2 <  ≤ 3) and Pr( = 3)are equal to find the value of Pr( = 3) and the value is 0.2.
(b)For the value of Pr( = 4)and Pr( = 6), both of the answers are 0.
(c)Pr(3 ≤  ≤ 5)= 1-0.6=0.4
(d)Pr(3 <  ≤ 6)=0.2
(d)Is the population mean  = E() equal to the sum of product of all possible values (which are X= 1, 2, 3, 5)with their corresponding probabilities?

Thanks for your precious time solving my problem!
Thank you!!!!

Comment: ps. enter the image to see the cdf

Comment: Please learn how to use math formatting on this site to avoid images, which not all users can access.

Comment: Sorry, could you teach me how to use the math formatting or where can I learn it? Thanks. @BruceET

Comment: See [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely right.

You can also derive the pmf, if you want being

$$P(X=x)=F_X(x)-F_X(x^-)$$

Thus you immediately realize that your rv takes the values

$$\{1;2;3;5\}$$

with probabilities

$$\{0.3;0.3;0.2;0.2\}$$

respectively

Comment: Direct and to the point (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You should begin working such a problem by plotting the CDF.
In this problem the CDF should look a lot like the empirical CDF (ECDF) of my sample (using R) simulated from your distribution. With a million observations, simulated
values should be accurate to two or three significant digits.

```
set.seed(220)
x = sample(c(1,2,3,5), 10^6, rep=T, p = c(.3,.3,.2,.2))
```

Approximate probability distribution:

```
table(x)/10^6
x
       1        2        3        5 
0.300511 0.298717 0.200321 0.200451
```

Approximated values of $E(X), Var(X), SD(X):$

```
mean(x)
[1] 2.501163   # aprx E(X) = 2.5
sd(x)
[1] 1.433084   # aprx SD(X) = 1.432
```

Approximate CDF:

```
plot(ecdf(x), lwd=2, col="blue")
 abline(h=0:1, col="green2")
```

[image]

Using R as a calculator, here are exact values of
$E(X)=2.5,\, Var(X)=2.05,\, SD(X)=1.431782\,:$

```
k = c(1,2,3,5);  p = c(.3,.3,.2,.2)
mu = sum(k*p);  mu
[1] 2.5          
vr = sum((k-mu)^2 * p); vr
[1] 2.05
sg = sqrt(vr);  sg
[1] 1.431782
```